# .htaccess, displaying 404 page without changing the user-entered url (no redirection)

Tags: .htaccess

So, my problem goes like this:
I created a custom 404 error page (error.html) and I want it to be displayed without actual redirection to the page, thus, keeping the user-entered URL. Examples:

> **User puts** *"http ://localhost/whatever.the.url/would/be"* **in their address bar.** 
>  
> **error.html displays, but the URL in the address bar remains as entered by user:**
>  *"http
> ://localhost/whatever.the.url/would/be"*

I tried other people's guides and answers but they didn't work for me, perhaps because I'm really amateur and I have no idea how .htaccess actually works, sorry.

In addition to that, my .htaccess currently looks like this:


`ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/www.minimalistik.de/fejle/404/fejl.html/`

Yeah it isn't much. Thanks to everyone who'd help me with this :)

Comment: Please clarify what is the current behaviour. It doesn't look like you've even tried to specify `error.html`?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument: _"Note that when you specify an ErrorDocument that points to a remote URL (ie. anything with a method such as http in front of it), Apache HTTP Server will send a redirect to the client to tell it where to find the document, even if the document ends up being on the same server."_

Comment: The trailing slash of the ErrrorDocument line seems superfluous. You should specify a file not a directory.

Comment: It is expected behavior that the URL does not change when displaying the error document. If you want to move to a different page add a line like the following to your error document: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20;url=/">

Comment: @Xypron "If you want to move to a different page add a line like the following to your error document" - Simply specifying an absolute URL in the `ErrorDocument` directive (as in the OPs example) will trigger a 302 redirect (as CBroe has already pointed out in comments above). However, that is not what the OP is wanting.

Answer (score 0):

To serve the error document via an internal subrequest (ie. the URL in the browser's address bar does not change) then simply specify a root-relative URL (starting with a slash) to your error document in the `ErrorDocument` directive (this is generally considered "normal" behaviour).

For example, if your `error.html` file is in the `/error-documents` subdirectory off the document root then you would use the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-documents/error.html
```

The user is *not* externally redirected to the error document.

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/www.minimalistik.de/fejle/404/fejl.html/
> ```

However, when you specify an absolute URL (ie. with scheme + hostname) as in this example then Apache triggers a 302 (temporary) redirect to the error document and the user is externally redirected. No "404 Not Found" response is returned to the client, unless the error document itself is returning a 404 status. And if it's returning a 200 OK (the default) then the error document itself could potentially be indexed by search engines! Needless to say, this is not recommended and is an error in most scenarios.

**Reference:**

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: oddly this didn't work in my case. then i figured it was because of other conflicting rules in htaccess! 